# DansGuardian: content regexp list for exact sites, how?

Tags: content-filter, dansguardian

We have contentregexplist file where we can write all substitutions like "source
regex"->"dest string"

And they ALL run for each page. Is it possible somehow to define a domain name(s) for which (only for 1 domain! not every page) some regexps should be looked for?

To be clear:
How to replace *"Google"->"garbage"* in page source only for host *host.example.org*?

May be other content filtering system can do this? Then which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, dansguardian cannot do this with content modification rules. You might be able to write your own squid helper to do it.

I know [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.net) is able to 'target' content mod rules (disclaimer: I work there) with their latest content filter - which is based on dg-like principles (The Dan is our CTO) but is a complete rewrite.